# Full height div doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I've a problem with simple html/css trick.

I want to create website with 100% height left bar with e.g. width 300px and on the right side i want contener div with the rest of the width.

below code:

```css
html {min-height:100%; position relative;}
body {margin:0px; height:100%;}
.left-bar {position:absolute; width:100px; background:#f8e8bc; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; overflow:hidden;}
.contener {float:right; right:0px; width: calc(100% - 100px); height:100%; background:#eee;}
.box {margin:auto; width:150px; height:500px; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid #ccc;}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="left-bar"></div>
      <div class="contener">
       <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`.

Comment: i can't use fixed position because all page must roll up and down, even left bar